# Paypal Express Checkout Recurring Payments - Popup Window Too Small

Tags: php, paypal, popup, recurring-billing

I am having an issue with the popup that paypal opens for recurring payments. Its too small. The Paypal page shows a "Your order summary" and that fills the whole popup. Users will get confused and not realise that to login, you have to scroll to the right to see the form. I have been search for a way to disable/hide that order summary so the form can show, or even have the page appear as the regular one time payment does where its just the login form.

I don't want this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgJim.jpg

I want this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/tu7cP.jpg

Using the integration wizard code:

```
<script>
var dg = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow(
{
    trigger: 'paypal_submit',
    expType: 'instant'
     //PayPal will decide the experience type for the buyer based on his/her 'Remember me on your computer' option.
});
</script>
```

and code:

```
function CallShortcutExpressCheckout( $paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, $cancelURL, $paymentStartdate) 
{

    $nvpstr="&AMT=". $paymentAmount;
    $nvpstr .= "&PAYMENTACTION=" . $paymentType;
    $nvpstr .= "&BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION=".urlencode("Denise Austin 360 Weekly Payments");
    $nvpstr .= "&BILLINGTYPE=RecurringPayments";
    $nvpstr .= "&RETURNURL=" . $returnURL;
    $nvpstr .= "&CANCELURL=" . $cancelURL;
    $nvpstr .= "&CURRENCYCODE=" . $currencyCodeType;
            $nvpstr .= "&PROFILESTARTDATE=" . urlencode($paymentStartdate);
            $nvpstr .= "&NOSHIPPING=1";
            $nvpstr .= "&SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole";

    $resArray=hash_call("SetExpressCheckout", $nvpstr);
    $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
    if($ack=="SUCCESS" || $ack=="SUCCESSWITHWARNING")
    {
        $token = urldecode($resArray["TOKEN"]);
        $_SESSION['TOKEN']=$token;
    }

    return $resArray;
}
```

Comment: can share your html and javascript in where you are opening the pop up? We cant help you w/o this

Comment: can you try this  var dgFlowMini = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlowMini instead of this var dg = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow(

Comment: I tried that and it just opens it in a new tab and not in a popup. I like the experience of the popup.